# python live data in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

this code print live data but i want output in excel with only price change like this--->

| symbol | price |
| --- | --- |
| DOGEUSDT | 0.0633400 |
| BTCUSDT | 21013.040 |
| LTCUSDT | 60.9000 |

code---->>>
`

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

ltp_data= []

crypto = {"BTCUSDT",  "LTCUSDT", "DOGEUSDT"}
def live_ltp():
    responses = []
    for i in crypto:
        key = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol="
        url = key+i
        response = requests.get(url)
        Ltp = response.json()
        ltp_data.append(Ltp)
        responses.append(Ltp)
    return responses
while True:
    print(str(live_ltp()))
```

`

Comment: do you want the mean or each row a value each time ?

Comment: value change without adding extra rows

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
while True:
    stats = pd.DataFrame(live_ltp())
    with pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx') as excel_writer:
        stats.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name='live_ltp', index=False)
```

maybe have a time.sleep at the end so it isn't spamming the API too.

Comment: Be careful as this is an infinite loop. You could end up in troubles when debugging, yada, yada.

Comment: Not when you're debugging surely, there's a pause button on most debuggers.  I think having it in production code would be questionable.  Not doubting your expertise obviously.

Comment: For completion, nor me yours, we can disagree, and I wish you a good week-end!

Answer (score -1):

If I understood well, you want to update an excel file using the while loop. If you put your request in a dataframe, it is easily done using openpyxl. The following works well, as long as the file is close.

```
import openpyxl

try:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine = 'openpyxl', mode = 'a', if_sheet_exists = 'overlay') as writer:
        YourOutputDataFrame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet_name, index = False) #Write output in a specific sheet (by name or index)
        writer.book.close() #Close (and save) Excel file
except:
    pass
```

Hope this helps. Do not hesitate to ask more about formatting, etc. if needed.

Comment: You don't need to close the book explicitly because the with statement implicitly closes.  Also exceptions should never pass silently.

Comment: Hello @Crapicus, the pass statement can be seen as 'do something here' as I do not see the point to provide the author with a fully operating code. Also, if you spend more time working with openpyxl, you will see that having this close statement will prevent many hours of suffering; somehow.

Comment: Hi @Cairoknox I've spent more time in Openpyxl than most to be honest.  Also Except: pass can be taken literally by people which is why I prefer examples without it.  Purely because people do tend to cut and paste.  If someone wants to implement error correction I'd let them read up on it without recommending something against the Zen of Python i.e. Errors should never pass silently.  Cheers.

Comment: I'm not doubting your expertise, Best.

Comment: Nor me yours.   We can disagree and I'm not offended :)